# IE8: drop event does not work inside CKEditor

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

First, it works well in a text input:

```
jQuery('#edit-title').bind('drop', function() {
  console.log('test jquery')
});
```

But when I test it inside CKEditor it does not work. I try both methods, as below:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('myplugin', {
  init: function (editor) {
    editor.on('contentDom', function (evt) {
      $(editor.document.$).bind('drop', function(evt) {
        console.log('drop 1');
      });
      editor.document.on('drop', function (evt) {
        console.log('drop 2');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try with another event, like 'click', both methods work. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... I'd check first whether IE8 supports D&D events. Perhaps jQ somehow mocks drop event on input, but it can be incompatible with contenteditable. It's a blind guess though.

Comment: Yes IE5+ support the 'drop' event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536929(v=vs.85).aspx, so it should work. Also, there is a bug in jQuery with drop event in IE8, but only when binding with 'live' http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6578, so I don't think it is related.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D2cjE/2/ example. Try to select the word "test" and drag and drop into the textfield and richtext editor.

Answer (score 0):

try only this code, it works for me: 
Maby it was not working for you because the Jquery part is crashing or something.. 
Did you try with a debugger. To see if the ContentDom event is fired?

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('myplugin', {
  init: function (editor) {
    editor.on('contentDom', function (evt) {
        editor.document.on('drop', function (ev) {
            console.log('drop 2'); 
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try without jQuery. About the contentdom event, yes, it works. As I wrote in the OP, I tried the 'click' event and it worked inside.

Comment: Just a note - as mentioned in [contentDom event doc](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) it's better to use [`editable#attachListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener) instead of `target#on` if `target` is related to content. There were issues caused by not using it in CKEditor and 3rd party libs.